# Throwing error when adding object to a 2d list?

Tags: python, compiler-errors, pygame

i am trying to initialise a game board where I add a piece object to an internal representation of the board. However I keep getting an error:

> ```
> File "/Users/student/PycharmProjects/pythonProject4/Board.py", line 20, in __init__
>    self.board[row].append(Piece(row, col))
> TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
> ```

```
import Constants as c
class Piece:

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0
        self.isActive = False
        self.pieces = 12
        self.radius = c.SQUARE // 2 - 8

    def getLoc(self, row, col):
        self.x = c.SQUARE * col + c.SQUARE // 2
        self.y = c.SQUARE * row + c.SQUARE // 2
```

```
import Constants as con
import pygame as pg
import Player as Piece


class Board:
    columns = 8
    rows = 8


    def __init__(self):
        self.board = []
        for row in range(8):
            self.board.append([])
            for col in range(8):
                even = (row + col) % 2 == 1
                if even:
                    self.board[row].append(0)
                elif row <= 2:
                    self.board[row].append(Piece(row, col))
                elif row >= 5:
                    self.board[row].append(Piece(row, col))
                else:
                    self.board[row].append(1)
```

Would anybody be able to help me with this? I want to make the checkers game, at the moment i have a 2d list in which 0=never occupied, 1=currently unoccupied, `PieceTeamOne(r,c)` and `PieceTeamTwo(r,c)`

Comment: What do you think calling the class `Piece(row, col)` does? Do you you think your class object returns anything that you can append?

Comment: You imported the `Player` module under the name `Piece`, and you try to call it as a function in `Piece(row, col)`. Did you mean `from Player import Piece`? We can't know as you didn't provide the relevant code. As a side note, you should respect the Python convention of using capitalized names for classes, and lowercase for module names.

Comment: @Rabbid76 I will, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@Thierry Lathuille already mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69842725/throwing-error-when-adding-object-to-a-2d-list/69857503#comment123458409_69842725), I think the problem in your code is with this part:

```
import Player as Piece
```

You should change that part to:

```
from Player import Piece
```